# Azure Devops Tracking committed vs actuals

Tags: azure-devops, reporting

My organization is trying to find an out of the box way with Azure DevOps to see which features were 'committed to' at the start of the release, and which are delivered. The Velocity report would be perfect, except Features are assigned to areas that are configured to run off of sprints that are child-iterations of larger release-iterations, and we want the data at the release-iteration level.

We're able to build queries that can mostly deliver this, but that method doesn't track changes, just shows you a current point in time view of how things are.

The goal is to have data we can use to evaluate if we're making commitments we can keep.

How have other organizations tackled this sort of problem? How do you tie committed vs. actuals at the Feature level?

Answer (score 0):

I could understand your requirements. But based on my test, `Velocity Report` has some limitations:

For example:

- If the Iteration Path has Child Iteration, it will show the child Iteration on Velocity Report. As you said , release-iteration  will not show in the Report.

So it cannot meet all your needs.

I tested some related extensions and existing charts, and it seems that there is no tool that can improve or replace the `Velocity Report` .

For a workaround:

For Child Iteration, you still could use the `Velocity Report` to record the process.

For the Parent Iteration, you could create different queries to show the process(Planned
, Completed,Completed Late and so on). You can use query to get the work item list of the corresponding state.

Here are examples:

Planned :

[image]

Completed:

[image]

...

Then you could add them to the Dashboards(Query Title Widget):

[image]

On the other hand, this requirement is valuable.

You could add your request for this feature on [our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Comment: For your Planned query, it doesn't show moved Stories, right? How do I show User Stories moved in a sprint?